# Problema con el vector

Tags: array, bucle-for

Tengo este vector intentando recolectar individualmente los diferentes valores que fueron declarados antes en 'n', pero por alguna razón me pone como numero mayor y menor el primer numero que se declara:

```
        int n, nMayor = 0, nMenor= 0;
        Scanner L = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros a comprobar: ");
        n=Integer.parseInt(L.nextLine());
        int[] valor= new int[n];
            for(int con=0;con<n;con++){
                System.out.print("Ingrese el ("+(con+1)+") numero: ");
                valor[con]=Integer.parseInt(L.nextLine());              
            }
            for(int va=0;va<n;va++){
                int s=0;
                if(valor[s]>=valor[va]){
                    nMayor=valor[s];
                }else{s=va;}
            }
            for(int va=0;va<n;va++){
                int s=0;
                if(valor[s]<=valor[va]){
                    nMenor=valor[s];
                }else{s=va;}
            }
        System.out.print("El numero mayor es: "+nMayor+" \n El numero menor es: "+nMenor);
```

no entiendo si solo esta cogiendo el primer valor o hay algo mal en la estructura for que verifica si es mayor o no, alguien porfavor puede decirme en que estoy fallando?

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero usar [Integer.MIN_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) y [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) para realizar las comparaciones, para determinar el maximo valor usa el valor mínimo posible y compara cada valor, si es mayor lo almacenas en la variable `nMayor`. Algo similar para obtener el valor minimo, compara cada valor con el valor máximo y si es menor lo vas almacenando en la variable `nMenor`

incluso esto funcionará para valores negativos.

```
    int n, nMayor = Integer.MIN_VALUE, nMenor= Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Scanner L = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros a comprobar: ");
    n=Integer.parseInt(L.nextLine());
    int[] valor= new int[n];
        for(int con=0;con<n;con++){
            System.out.print("Ingrese el ("+(con+1)+") numero: ");
            valor[con]=Integer.parseInt(L.nextLine());              
        }
        for(int va=0;va<n;va++){
            //int s=0;
            if(valor[va]>=nMayor){
                nMayor=valor[va];
            }/*else{s=va;}*/
        }
        for(int va=0;va<n;va++){
            //int s=0;
            if(valor[va]<=nMenor){
                nMenor=valor[va];
            }/*else{s=va;}*/
        }
    System.out.print("El numero mayor es: "+nMayor+" \n El numero menor es: "+nMenor);
```

Comment: No me queda muy claro como funciona  el max value y el min value

Comment: Integer.MIN_VALUE contiene el valor minimo de un valor entero, entonces realizas un bucle en donde compararas el primer valor si es mayor que este valor y lo almacenas en nMayor, el siguiente valor de tu array lo comparas ahora con nMayor si es mayor se almacena, si no continua comprobando el siguiente.

Comment: ok ya entendi eso, pero por decir en el codigo original que era lo que fallaba?

Comment: ok, además de lo mencionado, esta comparación : if(valor[s]>=valor[va]){ debe ser:  if(valor[va]>=nMayor){ , si es mayor, vas actualizando el valor de nMayor con el valor de valor[va] . Recuerda que si esta respuesta ayudo a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta,puedes marcarla como solución , revisa [tour], saludos.